# handsontable undoes only last cell changed

Tags: handsontable, undo

Our implementation of handsontable works pretty as per samples, but unlike the samples online, our undo only goes back one cell history change. Meaning, if we change cell 1, cell 2 and cell 3 and press Ctrl+Z 3 times, only the last cell keeps undoing and redoing. Any thoughts ?

-thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was related to our saving and reloading the data after saving. Without reloading the data, it does allow consecutive undoes.